# Include Images with Reply in Mail?

Tags: mail.app

In Mail (connected to my work Exchange server, if that matters), when I forward an email which contains inline images they are preserved.  However, if I *reply* to the email then they are not preserved.  They are instead replaced with something like this:

```
<image001.jpg>
```

Is there a way to preserve the images in a reply?

Comment: I suppose that is because it usually makes no sense to include attachments again in a reply. I have no solution to your question, though.

Comment: @leberwurstsaft: In the simplest cases, I would agree.  In longer email chains where people get added to the conversation late in the game it's very handy.

Comment: If someone comes in late you can always forward them the original mail for reference. Otherwise you'd have to send the images back and forth all the time. Not exactly space-saving ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Mail.app go to the Edit menu, go down to Attachments, then select Include Original Attachments with Reply.

Comment: Great, would've never occured to me to look for what are essentially preferences in the Edit menu :o

Comment: Me either.  Not very intuitive.  I always expect to find it in Preferences > Composing and end up back here every time :)

Comment: That is a good solution. But a more decent solution would be: "don't include attachments when reply unless it is an inline image". But I don't think it would be possible.